# Reference a vscode extension inside a Markdown file

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

Is there any way to reference vscode extensions inside a Markdown file, as we do with links: `[the link name](the_link_url)`?

Comment: For example, for the extension prettier use this link (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) . Search in https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/vscode

Comment: @Helena Thanks! This will do. But is there any way to link it directly to the extensions tab within vscode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Search for an extension here: [vscode marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/vscode)
2. Select the extension of your choice (I'm gonna have [docker](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.vscode-docker) as
   an example)
3. Find the green "Install" button and open it in a new tab.
4. On the new tab you will see the url has a text like this one:
   `vscode:extension/ms-azuretools.vscode-docker` This is the text you
   need to put in your link url to **directly** open your extension in vscode. You can also notice it if you mouseover the "Install" button at the bottom left corner of your browser (pic attached)

Please note that you can also search from within the extensions tab in vscode, and once you find your extension right click and "Copy Extension ID" but you would still have to prepend the text with "vscode:extension/"

[image: extension peak]

Comment: Thanks! This worked well. However, for me at least, there is no longer an "Install" button, it just brings up a command to use in the vscode command palette, but if I just add "vscode:extension/<the_extension_id>" the link works!.

Answer (score 1):

The format for a markdown link to an extension is:

```
[The link text](vscode:extension/*the-extension-id*)
```

for example

```
[Highlight extension by Fabio Spampinato](vscode:extension/fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight)
```

Inside VSCode you can get the *the-extension-id* for an extension as follows:

- go to the Extensions sidebar and find the extension of interest
- right-click the extension in the list and choose **Copy Extension ID**
- paste into your markdown